# load ontology from ontology document using OWL API

Tags: java, maven, owl, owl-api

I downloaded OWL API maven project and opened OWL API Default Implementation. I just want to load an ontology but it gives me an error.

```
public static final IRI example_iri2 = IRI.create("http://mged.sourceforge.net/ontologies/MGEDOntology.owl");

public static void main(String[] arg) throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
    OWLDataFactoryImpl factoryImpl = new OWLDataFactoryImpl();
    ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new NoOpReadWriteLock();
    OWLOntologyManagerImpl managerImpl = new OWLOntologyManagerImpl(factoryImpl, readWriteLock);
    OWLOntology ontology = managerImpl.loadOntology(example_iri2);
}
```

The output is:

```
        SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    Exception in thread "main" org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyFactoryNotFoundException: Could not find an appropriate factory to load ontology from ontology document: <http://mged.sourceforge.net/ontologies/MGEDOntology.owl>
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1048)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:935)
        at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:891)
        at com.main.main.main(main.java:33)
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BUILD FAILURE
```

How can I fix this?
I tried this and it's not working.

```
File file = new File("pizza3.owl");
OWLOntology ontology = managerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
```

Comment: What means downloaded? It's a Maven project, thus, it's recommended to use it via a Maven dependency. The ontology looks ok, so I guess you're missing some libraries. If you don't use Maven, you have to add all OWL API Jar files to your class path.

Comment: And I suggest you to follow the OWL API examples: An `OWLOntologyManager` will be created via `OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();`

Comment: @AKSW no I added all dependency

Comment: Please use the code of my comment to create the `OWLOntologyManager`. And let us know whether it works

Comment: @AKSW thanks. but what is have to import for OWLManager?

Comment: What do you mean by import? You do you write your Java code? An IDE usually has autocompletion/import.

Comment: Could you solve the issue? If yes, please provide an answer and accept it. That's how Stackoverflow is supposed to work.

Comment: @AKSW I use NetBeans.
I can't work with owl Api because I can't load ontology.

Comment: WHY can't you load the ontology. Did you change your source code as we told you?

Answer (score 0):

The manager you created needs setup.

The recommended way is through OWLManager, in the apibinding module.

The recommended dependencies to use are the distribution or osgidistribution modules.